# Neo4j Webadmin - No JSP support

Tags: jsp, neo4j

After I run the Neo4j startup, I get an error about loading `JSP` support and when I navigate to the web admin (`http://localhost:7474/webadmin/`), it's a blank page.

This is just a straight download and unpack of the ZIP file.

Console output

```
7/3/13 10:28:09 AM org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Setting startup time
out to: 120000ms based on -1
7/3/13 10:28:09 AM org.neo4j.server.database.Database INFO: Loaded neo4j tuning
properties from conf/neo4j.properties
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.database.Database INFO: Successfully started
 database
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Starting Neo Server
on port [7474] with [40] threads available
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Enabling HTTPS on po
rt [7473]
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.modules.DiscoveryModule INFO: Mounted discov
ery module at [/]
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager INFO: Loaded server pl
ugin "CypherPlugin"
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager INFO: Loaded server pl
ugin "GremlinPlugin"
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.modules.RESTApiModule INFO: Mounted REST API
 at [/db/data/]
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.modules.ManagementApiModule INFO: Mounted ma
nagement API at [/db/manage/]
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.modules.WebAdminModule INFO: Mounted webadmi
n at [/webadmin]
10:28:12.689 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] v
ia org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer INFO: Mounting static co
ntent at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
10:28:12.754 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - jetty-6.1.25
10:28:12.839 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did no
t find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
10:28:13.910 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Started SelectChannelConnector@local
host:7474
7/3/13 10:28:14 AM org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer INFO: Server started on [h
ttp://localhost:7474/]
10:28:14.311 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Started SslSocketConnector@localhost
:7473
```

Lines of interest

```
7/3/13 10:28:12 AM org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer INFO: Mounting static co
ntent at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
10:28:12.754 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - jetty-6.1.25
10:28:12.839 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did no
t find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
10:28:13.910 [main] INFO  org.mortbay.log - Started SelectChannelConnector@local
host:7474
```

This is the closet post I could find, looks like the same error, but with running a service, mine is plain `Neo4j.bat`

[can't start neo4j service after moving directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296774/cant-start-neo4j-service-after-moving-directory)

Comment: make sure you have `org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
` in your `neo4j-server.properties`

Comment: @MohamedE.ManSour yep, it's set. Thanks!

Comment: OK, what happen after you run `Neo4j.bat` ?

Comment: @MohamedE.ManSour It was there already / by default, so the same, the error

Comment: You probably have a newer version of the jdk installed than neo4j is looking for